# Had to have happened or Must have happened

Tags: grammar, difference, modal-verbs

I wonder what is the difference here:

> It had to have happened today.
>
> It must have happened today.

To me the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 2):

'Had to' is equal to 'must'. There is no syntactic difference between the two.